# Unknown or bad format of datetime interval in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, intervals

The objective is very simple. I may convert the values of hours, minutes and seconds to zeroes. I've been deciding to get these values from datetime variable and subtract the time interval. The name of error is mentioned above.

```
if($_POST['performance'])
{   
$dt1 = strtotime ($_POST['begin']);
$dt2 = strtotime ($_POST['edge']);

$h1 = date('H', $dt1);
$i1 = date('i', $dt1);

$interval1 = new DateInterval("P{$h1}H{$i1}M");
$dt1->sub($interval1);

$s = $dt2 - $d1;

echo "<p>" . $s/(24*3600) . "</p>";
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The format for DateInterval is wrong you have "PT{$h1}H{$i1}M" you missed a T after the P

Comment: And `$dt1->sub()` makes no sense - $dt1 is not a DateTime instance, it is a mere integer.

Comment: Would it not be easier to do: `$dt1=strtotime('12:25:34'); $dt2=strtotime('13:35:36'); print gmdate('H:i:s',($dt2-$dt1));`  (which outputs: `01:10:02`)   Because the output of 0.0416666 for one hour is pretty useless?